# Multivariate Gaussian with correlated elements

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, random-matrices

Working with a random matrix $\mathbf{J}$ whose elements follow a gaussian distribution, I need to evaluate the following integral:

$$
\int \prod_{i, j=1}^{N} \sqrt{\frac{N}{2 \pi}} d J_{i j}\exp\left (-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j, k} J_{k i} A_{i j} J_{k j}+\sum_{k, j} B_{k j} J_{k j} + \frac{\tau}{\gamma}\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji}\right)$$

When $\tau=0$, the integral can be computed by shifting coordinates and then calculating the determinant of $\mathbf{A}$. However I do not know how to handle the terms dependent on $\tau$.

Any ideas or observations are always welcome. Thank you!

Comment: another user asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543072/gaussian-integral-over-matrix-elements-with-correlation) and then once [again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559383/gaussian-integral-over-all-possible-real-matrices)

Comment: see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354626/a-general-formula-for-gaussian-integrals-over-matrix-elements) too