# Gaussian integral over all possible real matrices

Tags: matrices, gaussian-integral

I am trying to compute the following gaussian integral over all possible real matrices $J$:

$$I=\int \exp\left\{-\frac{N}{2}\text{Tr}\left[\mathbf{J}\mathbf{A}\;\mathbf{J}^T+2\mathbf{BJ}-\gamma \mathbf{JJ} \right]\right\}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{J}$$

Where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are Hermitian matrices.

When $\gamma=0$ I can complete the square and integrate this Gaussian integral without any problem (assuming I know the eigenvalues and determinant of $\mathbf{A}$):

$$\mathbf{J}\mathbf{A}\;\mathbf{J}^T+2\mathbf{BJ}=\left(\mathbf{J}^T-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\right)\mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{J}-\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}$$

However for general $\gamma\in \mathbb{R}$ I cannot seem to know how to evaluate this integral by completing the square: $\mathbf{J}^T\mathbf{A}\;\mathbf{J}+2\mathbf{BJ}-\gamma \mathbf{JJ}$

$\mathbf{J}$ is real but not symmetric. when $\gamma=0$ this integral converges so I do not see any reason why it would not be generalised to general $\gamma$ with an appropriate $\mathbf{A}$.

Any remark or advice is always appreciated. Thank you.

Edit : A different way to express the integral $I$ is the following:

$$I=\int \left(\prod_{ij}\mathrm{d}J_{ij}\right)\exp\left\{-\frac{N}{2} \sum_{i, j, k} J_{k i} A_{i j} J_{k j}+N\sum_{k, j} B_{k j} J_{k j}+\frac{N\gamma}{2}\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji}\right\}$$

Assuming I already know the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ and thus $\det(\mathbf{A})$, how can I compute the integral $I$?

Comment: Should that be $- \gamma \,J^TJ$ instead?

Comment: Unfortunately not, otherwise I could have included it in the expression of $\mathbf{A}$. Here it is meant to be $\text{Tr}\mathbf{JJ}=\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji}$.

Comment: In that case, there is no way to "complete the square" here.  Do you have a way of computing the integral in a simple case such as $B = 0$ and $A = I$? I suspect that the integral does not converge for $A = 0$.

Comment: Also, it seems suspicious that the integral is written with $\mathbf{JJ}$ as opposed to $\mathbf J^2$.

Comment: In the case $A=I$ then I can compute $N^2$ integrals independently for every $J_{ij}$. To handle the $J_{ij}J_{ji}$ terms I can uncouple them by considering the sums for $i <j$ only: similar to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350062/how-can-we-do-a-gaussian-integral-over-matrix-elements

Comment: I wrote it $\mathbf{JJ}$ because I am applying the following measure to some quantity : $P(\mathbf{J}) \propto \exp \left[-\frac{N}{2\left(1-\tau^{2}\right)} \operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{J} \mathbf{J}^{T}-\tau \mathbf{J} \mathbf{J}\right)\right]$

Comment: Ah okay, I was hoping that there might have been a typo at some point (:

Comment: We can reduce this problem to the case where $A$ is a block matrix with blocks $I,-I,0$.  Find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^\dagger AP$ has this form, then apply the substitution $K = PJP^{-1}$.  Here, $P^\dagger$ denotes a conjugate-transpose.

Comment: Note, by the way, that the map $J \mapsto PJP^{-1}$ has determinant $1$, so there is no factor to multiply by here.

Comment: Another user asked this [previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464422/multivariate-gaussian-with-correlated-elements#comment7332921_3464422) but got not response so it should be useful to have a proper solution, in your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543072/gaussian-integral-over-matrix-elements-with-correlation) what is lacking in the answer posted?, I don't get all but it seems fine to me

Comment: In the previous question they assume that I have $\tau \text{Tr}(\mathbf{J}\mathbf{J}^T)$ whereas I need $\tau \text{Tr}(\mathbf{J}\mathbf{J})$. Therefore using a $\delta_{ij}$ in the sum does not make the trick.

Comment: yes but the thread ends with the user commenting back to this and the next day an edit is made addressing this point, since there is no further reply I asked because it looks correct to me and I'm unsure to what could be missing

Answer (score 2):

In principle you could  write the $J$ matrix as a $N\times N$ long "super"vector and then you would have a "simple" quadratic form $J_{ij} \Gamma^{ijkl} J_{kl}$ where all the transposes etc are encoded in the $\Gamma$ super matrix. By redefining an index pair ${ij}=\alpha$ you could put the $\Gamma$ tensor in a "super" matrix form and find the relevant determinant etc. It looks daunting, but maybe there are some shortcuts, e.g. there is  a super matrix $\mathcal T$ that transforms any "super"vector into it's transpose.

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea of writing the $J$ matrix as a $N^2$ long "super" vector: my starting point is the following result:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}}  \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{x}\right\}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\frac{(2 \pi)^{n^{2} / 2}}{\sqrt{\operatorname{det}(\Sigma)}}$$
Where $\mathbf{\Sigma}\in \mathbb{R}^{N^2\times N^2}$

Integrating over all $\mathrm{d}J_{ij}$ is equivalent to integrating over all $\mathrm{d}x_i$ if we find an appropriate transformation. The main obstacle is this $\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji}$ sum. So I will consider here the following integral:

$$I=\int\left(\prod_{i j} \mathrm{d} J_{i j}\right) \exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j, k} J_{k i} A_{i j} J_{k j}-\frac{b}{2} \sum_{i j} J_{i j} J_{j i}\right\}$$

First, we can write:
$$b\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{l=1}^{n} J_{i j} J_{k l} \;\delta_{i l} \delta_{j k}b$$
Similarly:
$$\sum_{i, j, k} J_{k i} A_{i j} J_{k j}=\sum_{i, j, k} J_{i j} A_{jk} J_{i k}=\sum_{i, j, k,l} J_{i j} A_{jk} J_{l k}\delta_{il}=\sum_{i, j, k,l} J_{i j} A_{jl} J_{k l}\delta_{ik}$$
Thus our integral is now:
$$I=\int\left(\prod_{i j} \mathrm{d} J_{i j}\right) \exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j, k,l} J_{i j} A_{jl} J_{k l}\delta_{ik}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j,k,l}^{n}J_{i j} J_{k l} \;\delta_{i l} \delta_{j k}b\right\}$$

$$\implies I=\int\left(\prod_{i j} \mathrm{d} J_{i j}\right) \exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j, k,l} J_{i j} \left(A_{jl} \delta_{ik} +\delta_{i l} \delta_{j k}b\right)J_{k l}\right\}$$
Now, we can define $x$ such that :
$$x:=\left(\begin{array}{c}
J_{11} \\
J_{12} \\
\vdots \\
J_{1 n} \\
J_{21} \\
J_{22} \\
\vdots \\
J_{n n}
\end{array}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$$

Therefore:
$$J_{i j}= x_{n(i-1)+j} \quad \forall i, j \in \mathbb{N} \cap[1, n]$$
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_{n(i-1)+j, n(k-1)+l}= A_{jl} \delta_{ik} +\delta_{i l} \delta_{j k}b\quad \forall i, j, k, l \in \mathbb{N} \cap[1, n]
\end{equation}

For N=2 we have:
$$\Sigma=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 A_{1,1}+b & A_{1,2} & 0 & 0 \\
 A_{2,1} & A_{2,2} & b & 0 \\
 0 & b & A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} \\
 0 & 0 & A_{2,1} & A_{2,2}+b \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
For general $N\in \mathbb{N}$ we recover : $\Rightarrow x^{T} \Sigma x=\sum_{i,j,k,l}^{n} J_{i j}\left(A_{jl} \delta_{ik} +\delta_{i l} \delta_{j k}b\right) J_{k l}$

Using our initial result we see that 
$$I=\frac{(2 \pi)^{n^{2} / 2}}{\sqrt{\operatorname{det}(\Sigma)}}$$

Thus our problem is reduced to finding the determinant of the following $N^2\times N^2$ matrix: $\Sigma_{n(i-1)+j, n(k-1)+l}= A_{jl} \delta_{ik} +b \delta_{i l} \delta_{j k}$. This is where my answer ends. It would be interesting to derive a formula to compute the determinant of $\Sigma$.

After tinkering I find that:

In the case $N=2$:

$\operatorname{det}(\Sigma)=|A+bI|(|A|-|bI|)$

In the case $N=3$:

$\operatorname{det}(\Sigma)=|A+bI|\left(|A|^2-b^2\operatorname{Tr}(A)|A|-|bI|^2+b^4\operatorname{Tr}(\Lambda^2A)\right)$

Where $\operatorname{Tr}\left(\Lambda^2A\right)$ is the trace of the $k$th exterior power of A, taken from this formula:
$$
|A-bI|=-\sum_{k=0}^{n} b^{n-k}(-1)^{k} \operatorname{tr}\left(\Lambda^{k} A\right)
$$
It would be interesting to solve for general $N$. I might create a new post on this question.

Comment: So as I understand the trick was to used a delta twice and not [once](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543072/gaussian-integral-over-matrix-elements-with-correlation#comment7318609_3543072), what I don't get is why appears a factor of $|A-Ib|$ in the cases you wrote

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, I made a mistake: the correct term is $|A+bI|$ and not $|A-Ib|$. I edited my answer.

Comment: Actually now I have another problem I read that we have $\Sigma=A_{jl} \delta_{ik} +b \delta_{i l}\delta_{j k}=A+bI$ but is $I=\delta_{i l}\delta_{j k}$ shouldn't $\delta_{i l}\delta_{j k}$ be identified to a real value (trace) instead of a matrix or I'm just reading things wrong

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly: indeed $A_{j l} \delta_{i k}+b \delta_{i l} \delta_{j k}\neq A+b I$. I edited my answer and added a representation of $\Sigma$ in the case $N=2$. Did I misunderstood your problem?

Comment: I thought I did but now with your example I think I get it